# Why gdb is in continue stage for hours?

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, gdb, qemu

I'm trying to debug Linux kernel using QEMU and gdb. When i connect QEMU with gdb i received the following output.

```
(gdb) target remote localhost:1234
Remote debugging using localhost:1234
0xffffffff87df72d2 in ?? ()
```

I don't get how to decode `0xffffffff87df72d2 in ?? ()`. Then i set a breakpoint and executed the `continue` command and it's running for hours. Much helpful if someone could help me to reslove this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

0xffffffff87df72d2 is the program counter of the guest at the point where you interrupted it. "??" means that gdb has no source level information about that address.